# 電気回路系の質問　DC電源(-)をサーボモータのGNDに直接繋ぐと誤作動になる

Tags: arduino

ESP32でMG996Rを動かすためにDC電源から直接つないだところ、
サーボモータが暴れ出しました。

結局
DC電源(-) → Servo(GND) → ESP32(GND)と直列に繋ぐことで解決しましたが原因はなぜでしょう？

ちなみにDCは６Vです。

おそらくPWMの分電圧が上がるため、DC電源-6Vでは電圧が０にならずに？？不具合？
なのかなと考えていますが、
ESP32（GND)は電圧０Vという訳でもないですよね？

Comment: 電気回路図が無いと「回答」は無理っす。この手の質問は回路図があって当たり前、回路パターンがあって初めて質疑応答になります。根拠なしに「たまたまうまくいっている」場合、同様に「たまたまうまくいかなくなる」のでちゃんと原因と対策を理解したうえで実践が必要ですよ。

Answer (score 1):

モータというのはコイルの塊です。これをPWMなどパルスで駆動すると、盛大にノイズが発生します
このノイズがCPUの信号ラインや電源ラインに飛び込むと、CPUは暴走したりして誤動作を起こすことになります
ということで、電源とモーター、CPUの配線は経路や順番を気にしないとまずいです。